# adding a mancenter cluster config fails once a global serializer is configured

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to add a cluster config with a global-serializer in the hazelcast mancenter. So here is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast-client xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
              https://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-4.1.xsd">

    <cluster-name>ourClusterName</cluster-name>

    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>host.docker.internal:27100</address>
        </cluster-members>
    </network>

    <serialization>
        <serializers>
            <global-serializer override-java-serialization="true">mycompany.OurSerializer</global-serializer>
        </serializers>
    </serialization>

</hazelcast-client>
```

But this configuration doesn't work. I get an exception CLIENT_FAILED_TO_START. The strange thing is when I uncomment the serialization config, I can connect to the cluster.

I also added all the required libraries to the classpath: -e MC_CLASSPATH='/data/jars/*'

Here are my technical details:

- Hazelcast 4.1
- Mancenter 4.2020.12
- Working with the dockerImage: hazelcast/management-center:4.2020.12

any ideas why this doesnt work

Comment: Could you please enable debug logging as described in https://github.com/hazelcast/management-center-docker#changing-logging-level and share more details about the client startup error?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It sems that my serializer class was not found. But it looks like that the MC_CLASSPATH='/data/jars/*' is added to the java command line. is there something wrong with my syntax '/data/jars/*' or is there any other error??

Comment: You might want to try listing the JAR files directly instead of using `*`.

Comment: even when I try to a single jar the same happens. here is my whole command I execute: docker run --rm -m 512m -v C:\devsbb\mancenterdemo:/data -e LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG -e MC_CLASSPATH='/data/jars/*' -p 8080:8080 hazelcast/management-center:4.2020.12

Comment: when i build a dedicated dockerfile everything works fine. so i go with that approach...